# Kafka expectantly shutting down. License topic could not be created

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

On Kafka startup multiple messages are logged to `kafka/logs/kafkaServer.out` and contain:

> INFO [Admin Manager on Broker 0]: Error processing create topic
> request CreatableTopic(name='_confluent-license', numPartitions=1,
> replicationFactor=3, assignments=[],
> configs=[CreateableTopicConfig(name='cleanup.policy',
> value='compact'), CreateableTopicConfig(name='min.insync.replicas',
> value='2')]) (kafka.server.AdminManager)

After approx 15 minutes Kafka shuts down and outputted to
`kafka/logs/kafkaServer.out` is :

> ```
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
> [2020-12-08 04:04:15,951] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
> ```
>
> (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could not be created
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException:
> Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1.
> [2020-12-08 04:04:15,952] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

It appears Kafka shuts down because the replication factor is set to 3 for the topic `_confluent-license` ? I'm not creating the topic `_confluent-license`, is this created as part of Kafka startup for licensing check ?

In attempt to fix I've modified `/v5.5.0/etc/kafka/server.properties` so that replication factor is 1 for internal topics:

```
############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
```

instead of 3 :

```
#offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
#transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
```

But this does not fix the issue and same logs are generated. The replication factor of __consumer_offsets is still 3. How to reduce the replication factor of topic `_confluent-license` from 3 to 1 ? Or could there be an alternative issue that is causing Kafka to shutdown ?

Comment: Note that the second error says Error checking or creating **metrics topic**, which has its own setting separate from the license topic. I've rolled back your question because that isn't part of the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the property `confluent.license.topic.replication.factor` by default it is 3.

Answer (score 3):

> (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: License topic could
> not be created Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException:
> Replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1. [2020-12-08
> 04:04:15,952] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down
> (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

The above error is due to the **license topic having a default replication factor as 3**. The same can be configured with `confluent.license.topic.replication.factor` to be equal to 1 if you have only 1 broker. The documentation for the same is [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/license-configs.html#confluent.license.topic.replication.factor).

> [2020-12-08 07:46:02,241] ERROR Error checking or creating metrics topic (io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidReplicationFactorException: Replication factor: 2 larger than available brokers: 1.

The above error is due to the **Confluent Metrics Reporter being enabled**. The **replication factor for the metric topic is defaulted at 3** and can be configured with `confluent.metrics.reporter.topic.replicas` to be 1 if you have just one broker. The documentation for the same is [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/metrics-reporter.html#configuration-options).

Answer (score -2):

The property `confluent.license.topic.replication.factor` is not working as expected.

Instead, we can try anyone of these properties `confluent.license.replication.factor=1` or  `confluent.license.admin.replication.factor=1` if the number of broker is `1`. This property is not in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation is here - https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/license-configs.html Where you can see that `confluent.license.topic.replication.factor` is correct

Comment: Did you submit a bug to Confluent support regarding this issue you're having? I'd be useful if you showed the logs proving it doesn't work. I'm not able to find any references to these other two properties you've mentioned

Comment: yes, it was via confluent support ticket.